# prefix cannot be "null" when creating a QName

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using the WSO2 ESB version 4.8.1. I tested sample no 658( Smooks Mediator transformation xml -> xml) I only changed in configuration  paths to  folders (I don't have folder '/home/lakmali/...':-)).This sample not work. Error from log:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix cannot be "null" when creating a QName.

Full log with error:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,589]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon... {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,605]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 7 6.1, amd64 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,605]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,605]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.7.0_40 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,605]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.0-b56,Oracle Corporation {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,605]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : C:\Java\WSO2ES~1.1\bin\.. {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,605]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : C:\Java\WSO2ES~1.1\bin\..\tmp {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,605]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : ******* {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,745]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile. {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,761]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created ! {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:13,776]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:19,051]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 39ms {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:19,113]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:19,769]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully. {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:21,563]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,530]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ClusterBuilder} -  Clustering has been disabled {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ClusterBuilder}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,826]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.landing.page.deployer.LandingPageWebappDeployer} -  Deployed product landing page webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/home] {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.landing.page.deployer.LandingPageWebappDeployer}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,826]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,873]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} -  Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,889]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.config.ClientConnFactoryBuilder} -  HTTPS Loading Identity Keystore from : repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.config.ClientConnFactoryBuilder}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,889]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.config.ClientConnFactoryBuilder} -  HTTPS Loading Trust Keystore from : repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.config.ClientConnFactoryBuilder}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,920]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} -  Pass-through HTTPS Sender started... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,920]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} -  Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,920]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} -  Pass-through HTTP Sender started... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:22,935]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender} -  VFS Sender started {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:23,045]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:23,310]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: Echo.aar - file:/C:/Java/WSO2ES~1.1/bin/../repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Echo.aar {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:23,575]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:23,825]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:23,934]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: Version.aar - file:/C:/Java/WSO2ES~1.1/bin/../repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Version.aar {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:24,043]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:24,199]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener} -  Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:24,667]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} -  Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:24,683]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.PollTableEntry} -  transport.vfs.FileURI parameter is missing in the proxy service configuration {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.PollTableEntry}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:24,870]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer} -  Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1-wso2v10 - file:/C:/Java/WSO2ES~1.1/bin/../repository/deployment/client/modules/addressing-1.6.1-wso2v10.mar {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:24,885]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer} -  Deploying module: rampart-1.6.1-wso2v8 - file:/C:/Java/WSO2ES~1.1/bin/../repository/deployment/client/modules/rampart-1.6.1-wso2v8.mar {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:24,901]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender} -  TCP Sender started {org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:25,712]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor -  {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:25,712]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.store -  {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:26,321]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:26,430]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.sts -  {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:26,617]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.tryit -  {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:26,820]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Repository       : C:\Java\WSO2ES~1.1\bin\../repository/deployment/server/ {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:26,960]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:26,991]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} -  Starting ESB... {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,007]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} -  Initializing Apache Synapse... {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,007]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory} -  Using Synapse home : C:\Java\WSO2ES~1.1\. {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,007]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory} -  Using synapse.xml location : C:\Java\WSO2ES~1.1\.\.\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,007]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory} -  Using server name : localhost {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,023]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory} -  The timeout handler will run every : 15s {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,023]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController} -  Initializing Synapse at : Wed Feb 12 10:33:27 CET 2014 {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,023]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.CarbonSynapseController} -  Loading the mediation configuration from the file system {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.CarbonSynapseController}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,023]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder} -  Building synapse configuration from the synapse artifact repository at : .\.\repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs\default {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,023]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.XMLConfigurationBuilder} -  Generating the Synapse configuration model by parsing the XML configuration {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.XMLConfigurationBuilder}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,101]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfigurationBuilder} -  Loaded Synapse configuration from the artifact repository at : .\.\repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs\default {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfigurationBuilder}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,116]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController} -  Loading mediator extensions... {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,116]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController} -  Deploying the Synapse service... {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,116]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController} -  Deploying Proxy services... {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,116]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Building Axis service for Proxy service : ssXMLProxy {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,116]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Adding service ssXMLProxy to the Axis2 configuration {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,132]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: ssXMLProxy {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,225]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : ssXMLProxy {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,225]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController} -  Deployed Proxy service : ssXMLProxy {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,225]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Building Axis service for Proxy service : FirmaXMLProxy {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,241]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Adding service FirmaXMLProxy to the Axis2 configuration {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,241]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: FirmaXMLProxy {super-tenant} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,303]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : FirmaXMLProxy {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,303]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController} -  Deployed Proxy service : FirmaXMLProxy {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,303]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController} -  Deploying EventSources... {org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,319]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.ServerManager} -  Server ready for processing... {org.apache.synapse.ServerManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,350]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bam.mediationstats.data.publisher.internal.MediationStatisticsComponent} -  Statistic Reporter is Disabled {org.wso2.carbon.bam.mediationstats.data.publisher.internal.MediationStatisticsComponent}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,350]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bam.mediationstats.data.publisher.internal.MediationStatisticsComponent} -  Can't register an observer for mediationStatisticsStore. If you have disabled StatisticsReporter, please enable it in the Carbon.xml {org.wso2.carbon.bam.mediationstats.data.publisher.internal.MediationStatisticsComponent}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,397]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.rule.kernel.internal.ds.RuleEngineConfigDS} -  Successfully registered the Rule Config service {org.wso2.carbon.rule.kernel.internal.ds.RuleEngineConfigDS}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,865]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener} -  Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,865]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener} -  Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8243 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,865]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} -  Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener... {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,881]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} -  Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8280 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,881]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener} -  VFS listener started {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:27,881]  INFO {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool} -  Using a shared selector for servlet write/read {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:28,130]  INFO {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool} -  Using a shared selector for servlet write/read {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:28,146]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.eventing.internal.RegistryEventingServiceComponent} -  Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry {org.wso2.carbon.registry.eventing.internal.RegistryEventingServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:28,520]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:28,520]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Server           :  WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus-4.8.1 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:28,520]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 22 sec {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:33:28,910]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://10.104.0.44:9443/carbon/ {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:35:38,588] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator} -  Failed to filter source. {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator}
org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:86)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:61)
    at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:516)
    at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:475)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator.mediate(SmooksMediator.java:123)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFSTransportListener.java:597)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix cannot be "null" when creating a QName
    at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:251)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventAllocatorImpl.getQName(XMLEventAllocatorImpl.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventAllocatorImpl.getXMLEvent(XMLEventAllocatorImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventAllocatorImpl.allocate(XMLEventAllocatorImpl.java:53)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.next(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:248)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.stream.IOElementPipe.populateEvents(IOElementPipe.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.stream.IOElementPipe.getData(IOElementPipe.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.stream.ElementInputStream.read(ElementInputStream.java:61)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:70)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:75)
    ... 19 more
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-12 10:35:38,604] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener} -  Error processing File URI : file:///c:/java/test/toconvert/s481/input-message-658.xml {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener}
org.wso2.carbon.mediator.service.MediatorException: Failed to filter source. Caused by Failed to filter source.
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator.handleException(SmooksMediator.java:242)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.transform.SmooksMediator.mediate(SmooksMediator.java:137)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFSTransportListener.java:597)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Thanks in advance for response, Grzegorz

Answer (score 0):

the issue has been fixed with the wso2 enterprise service bus 4.9.0 for sample 658. Once the server stats in sample mode kindly update the folder paths from /home/lakmali in[1] to a folder location relevant for you and in the proxy service named synapse_sample_658.xml[2] available in path /wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/samples

[1]repository/samples/resources/smooks/smooks-config-658.xml  within the location `<file:destinationDirectoryPattern>`

[2]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <proxy name="SmooksSample" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
      <description />
      <target>
         <inSequence>
            <smooks config-key="smooks-key">
               <input type="xml" />
               <output type="xml" />
            </smooks>
         </inSequence>
      </target>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///home/shavantha/dev/test/smooks/in</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///home/shavantha/dev/test/smooks/original</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///home/shavantha/dev/test/smooks/original</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.xml</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   </proxy>
   <localEntry key="smooks-key" src="file:repository/samples/resources/smooks/smooks-config-658.xml" />
   <sequence name="fault">
      <log level="full">
         <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default &quot;fault&quot; sequence" />
         <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" />
         <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" />
      </log>
      <drop />
   </sequence>
   <sequence name="main">
      <log />
      <drop />
   </sequence>
</definitions>
```

The public jira for the issue you have raised is available on https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3608
regards,shavantha